# NASM counting program not working

Tags: x86, nasm, counting

I want to use only the instructions I have already used. I am unable to get the output, seems the input is never being read.

Could anyone please help me figure out the problem in my code?

```
section .data
space:db ' '
size :equ $-space
num :db 4
no :db 4

section .text
global _start
_start:
mov eax,3 ;read input number
mov ebx,0
mov ecx,num
mov edx,4
int 80h

sub dword[num],30h ;convert from ASCII to integer
again:    ;incrementing the eax register value from 0(loop)
mov eax,0
cmp eax,dword[num]
ja finish

mov dword[no],eax ;store eax value to no 
add eax,30h ;convert eax to ascii


mov edx,4. ;write eax value 
mov ecx,eax
mov ebx,1
mov eax,4
int 80h

inc dword[no] ;incrementing no 
mov eax,dword[no]
jmp again

finish:  ;exit
mov eax,1
mov ebx,0
int 80h
```

Comment: `db 4` emits one byte with value 4.  I think you want `resd` in the BSS section.  Use `strace` to see what system calls your code actually makes.  You didn't comment your code at all, and I don't feel like looking up the 32-bit system call numbers to figure out what system calls you're making.

Comment: Single step your code with a debugger.  Your code looks like it only wants to read a single-digit ASCII character, but then it's using DWORD loads/stores instead of BYTE.  You probably jump to `finish` every time.

Comment: I am a absolute beginner in nasm , thank you so much for the comments I'll try correcting them.

Comment: Why did you say that I jump to finish every time?

Comment: Oh, I didn't look closely at what you were doing.  It would have explained never seeing any output, and you're doing a DWORD compare on what should be just a BYTE.  What you're actually doing is unsigned `0 > num`, which is always false.  `JA` is taken if CF=0 and ZF=0, but `cmp eax=0, [num]` will always set one or the other.  Use your debugger to single step, and also run your program under `strace` to see what system calls it makes.

Comment: Post what the assignment actually requires, what you entered at the keyboard and what you expect the result to be.

Comment: Thank u all, I understood my mistake and corrected the code .